# How to run jsfiddle code in joomla 3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, jsfiddle, joomla3.2

I'm trying to run the following code in my Joomla site but it won't run. I am using Joomla 3.2 and the [code editor JCK](http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/edition/editors/jck-editor) but still I can't get the HTML tags to work propperly. So please help me to run the following code:

```js
    $("#text10").keyup(function() {
      $("#text10").blur();
      $("#text10").focus();
    });
    $("#text10").change(function() {
      var name = $('#text10').val();
      var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
      var specialChars = "<>@!#$%^&*()_+[]{}?:;|'\"\\,./~`-=";



      if (name == "" || name == " ") {
        //  alert('All Boxes have elements.');
        $("#equal").show();
        $("#equal a").html("please enter account number");

      } else if (name.match(numbers)) {
        $("#equal").hide();
        $("#equal a").html("correct account number"); //  alert('All Boxes have elements.');
      } else if (name.match(specialChars)) {
        $("#equal").show();
        $("#equal a").html("correct account number"); //  alert('All Boxes have elements.');
      } else {
        //  alert('All Boxes have elements.');
        $("#equal").show();
        $("#equal a").html("please check your account number  correctly");

      }

    });
```

```css
#products {
  font: 13px/20px'Lucida Grande', Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #404040;
  background: #f2f8fc;
}
.ui-widget-content ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0px;
  text-decoration: blink;
}
.ui-widget-content {
  min-height: 40px;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#equal {
  display: none;
}
#e1 {
  display: none;
}
.button-purple {
  background: #9966cb;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-color: #8040be #8040be #733aab;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a87dd3, #9966cb 66%, #8f57c6);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a87dd3, #9966cb 66%, #8f57c6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a87dd3, #9966cb 66%, #8f57c6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a87dd3, #9966cb 66%, #8f57c6);
}
.button-purple:active {
  background: #9966cb;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-color: #733aab #8040be #8040be;
}
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center top, farthest-corner, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center top, farthest-corner, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-image: -o-radial-gradient(center top, farthest-corner, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-image: radial-gradient(center top, farthest-corner, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}
.button:hover:before {
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(farthest-corner, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03));
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(farthest-corner, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03));
  background-image: -o-radial-gradient(farthest-corner, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03));
  background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-corner, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03));
}
.button:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.button:active:before {
  content: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.button-pink {
  background: #e8367f;
  border-color: #d31865 #d31865 #bc165a;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eb5190, #e8367f 66%, #e62473);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eb5190, #e8367f 66%, #e62473);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eb5190, #e8367f 66%, #e62473);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eb5190, #e8367f 66%, #e62473);
}
.button-pink:active {
  background: #e8367f;
  border-color: #bc165a #d31865 #d31865;
}
.button-orange {
  background: #f4902a;
  border-color: #df770c #df770c #c76a0a;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f69f47, #f4902a 66%, #f38617);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f69f47, #f4902a 66%, #f38617);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f69f47, #f4902a 66%, #f38617);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f69f47, #f4902a 66%, #f38617);
}
.button-orange:active {
  background: #f4902a;
  border-color: #c76a0a #df770c #df770c;
}
.button-green {
  background: #5ca934;
  border-color: #478228 #478228 #3c6f22;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #69c03b, #5ca934 66%, #54992f);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #69c03b, #5ca934 66%, #54992f);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #69c03b, #5ca934 66%, #54992f);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #69c03b, #5ca934 66%, #54992f);
}
.button-green:active {
  background: #5ca934;
  border-color: #3c6f22 #478228 #478228;
}
.button-red {
  background: #d5452f;
  border-color: #ae3623 #ae3623 #992f1f;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #da5c48, #d5452f 66%, #c73d28);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #da5c48, #d5452f 66%, #c73d28);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #da5c48, #d5452f 66%, #c73d28);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #da5c48, #d5452f 66%, #c73d28);
}
.button-red:active {
  background: #d5452f;
  border-color: #992f1f #ae3623 #ae3623;
}
.button-gray {
  background: #47494f;
  border-color: #2f3034 #2f3034 #232427;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #55585f, #47494f 66%, #3d3f44);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #55585f, #47494f 66%, #3d3f44);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #55585f, #47494f 66%, #3d3f44);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #55585f, #47494f 66%, #3d3f44);
}
.button-gray:active {
  background: #47494f;
  border-color: #232427 #2f3034 #2f3034;
}
.tasks {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 240px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #cdd3d7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.ui-widget-header {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  color: #5d6b6c;
  align: "center";
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  background: #f0f1f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7fd, #e6eaec);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7fd, #e6eaec);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7fd, #e6eaec);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5f7fd, #e6eaec);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}
.tasks-title {
  line-height: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Payers account number
<input type="text" name="text10" id="text10" size="25" />


<div width="100%" id="equal">
  <a href="#" class="button button-green"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have access to your template files? why do you use jck editor for this?

Comment: What you tried the whole code inside Joomla editor ? html,css,js ?

Comment: Chadocat@yes I have access of it and i am using jck editor because jck editor allow html tags

Comment: Jobin@i uploaded script in html tag but it destroy html tag when i save the Artical

Comment: @hirenpanchal check my answer it have different solution choose whcich one suite for your requirement

Comment: chadocat@some code still not working like<b id= "new"></b> etc.. if i assign <b> in to my code it destroy by joomla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your editor click on source on the left top. then enter this code :

```
<div id="custom_form">
    Payers account number
    <input type="text" name="text10" id="text10" size="25" />
    <div width="100%" id="equal"><a href="#" class="button button-green"></a></div>
</div>
<style>
#products{font: 13px/20px 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #404040;
  background: #f2f8fc;}
.ui-widget-content ul li
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 30px;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0 0px;
    text-decoration:blink;
}
.ui-widget-content
{
   min-height:40px;

}
.hidden{
    visibility:hidden;
}
#equal
{display:none;
}
#e1
{display:none;
}
.button-purple {
  background: #9966cb;
     color:#FFFFFF;
  border-color: #8040be #8040be #733aab;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a87dd3, #9966cb 66%, #8f57c6);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a87dd3, #9966cb 66%, #8f57c6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a87dd3, #9966cb 66%, #8f57c6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a87dd3, #9966cb 66%, #8f57c6);
}
.button-purple:active {
  background: #9966cb;
     color:#FFFFFF;
  border-color: #733aab #8040be #8040be;
}
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
     color:#FFFFFF;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center top, farthest-corner, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center top, farthest-corner, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-image: -o-radial-gradient(center top, farthest-corner, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-image: radial-gradient(center top, farthest-corner, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}
.button:hover:before {
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(farthest-corner, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03));
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(farthest-corner, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03));
  background-image: -o-radial-gradient(farthest-corner, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03));
  background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-corner, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03));
}
.button:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     color:#FFFFFF;
}
.button:active:before {
  content: none;
     color:#FFFFFF;
}

.button-pink {
  background: #e8367f;
  border-color: #d31865 #d31865 #bc165a;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eb5190, #e8367f 66%, #e62473);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eb5190, #e8367f 66%, #e62473);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eb5190, #e8367f 66%, #e62473);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eb5190, #e8367f 66%, #e62473);
}
.button-pink:active {
  background: #e8367f;
  border-color: #bc165a #d31865 #d31865;
}
.button-orange {
  background: #f4902a;
  border-color: #df770c #df770c #c76a0a;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f69f47, #f4902a 66%, #f38617);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f69f47, #f4902a 66%, #f38617);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f69f47, #f4902a 66%, #f38617);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f69f47, #f4902a 66%, #f38617);
}
.button-orange:active {
  background: #f4902a;
  border-color: #c76a0a #df770c #df770c;
}
.button-green {
  background: #5ca934;
  border-color: #478228 #478228 #3c6f22;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #69c03b, #5ca934 66%, #54992f);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #69c03b, #5ca934 66%, #54992f);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #69c03b, #5ca934 66%, #54992f);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #69c03b, #5ca934 66%, #54992f);
}
.button-green:active {
  background: #5ca934;
  border-color: #3c6f22 #478228 #478228;
}.button-red {
  background: #d5452f;
  border-color: #ae3623 #ae3623 #992f1f;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #da5c48, #d5452f 66%, #c73d28);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #da5c48, #d5452f 66%, #c73d28);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #da5c48, #d5452f 66%, #c73d28);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #da5c48, #d5452f 66%, #c73d28);
}
.button-red:active {
  background: #d5452f;
  border-color: #992f1f #ae3623 #ae3623;
}
.button-gray {
  background: #47494f;
  border-color: #2f3034 #2f3034 #232427;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #55585f, #47494f 66%, #3d3f44);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #55585f, #47494f 66%, #3d3f44);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #55585f, #47494f 66%, #3d3f44);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #55585f, #47494f 66%, #3d3f44);
}
.button-gray:active {
  background: #47494f;
  border-color: #232427 #2f3034 #2f3034;
}
.tasks {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 240px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #cdd3d7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.ui-widget-header {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  color: #5d6b6c;
    align:"center";
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  background: #f0f1f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7fd, #e6eaec);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7fd, #e6eaec);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f7fd, #e6eaec);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5f7fd, #e6eaec);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}

.tasks-title {
  line-height: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: inherit;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $("#text10").keyup(function(){
        $("#text10").blur();
        $("#text10").focus();
});
$("#text10").change(function(){
var name = $('#text10').val();
         var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;   
         var specialChars = "<>@!#$%^&*()_+[]{}?:;|'\"\\,./~`-=";



    if (name == "" || name == " " )
        {
           //  alert('All Boxes have elements.');
             $("#equal").show();
             $("#equal a").html("please enter account number");

        }


    else if(name.match(numbers))
    {
               $("#equal").hide();
             $("#equal a").html("correct account number");   //  alert('All Boxes have elements.');
    }

    else if(name.match(specialChars))
    {
               $("#equal").show();
             $("#equal a").html("correct account number");   //  alert('All Boxes have elements.');
    }
  else 
        {
           //  alert('All Boxes have elements.');
             $("#equal").show();
             $("#equal a").html("please check your account number  correctly");

        }

});
</script>
```

Then save your article and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

for adding custom HTML ,JS , PHP codes inside Joomla article.

You can use some extensions or create your own module for this,

In this case you are trying to add the codes into article section with Joomla editor.

The [Include HTML or PHP codes into joomla article](http://www.walkswithme.net/how-to-include-html-or-php-codes-into-joomla-article) will help you to solve .

Other wise simply edit the template file.

Hope its helps..